# Unable to install mysql connector for Python 3

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

In `Python 2.X` I used `MySQLdb` module. But recently I've started to port my application to `Python 3.X` and now indeed this module is no longer working. This is what I tried to do:

```
$ pip3 install MySQLdb
$ pip3 install PyMySQL
$ pip3 install mysql-connector-python
```

But none of these commands (taken from different `stackoverflow` threads) works. So I need some help.

Comment: What doesn't work?? Try running as root. Try the pip module directly from python: `sudo python3 -m pip install PyMySQL` (This is a pure python driver for mysql - should be compatible with MySQLdb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following code for installing sql connector for python3

pip install --allow-external mysql-connector-python mysql-connector-python

it worked for me...

[image: Solved installation]

Comment: Something has been installed. But how do you use it in code? What is the name of the module and where you see the api of the module?

Comment: I get this error on python3.4 "DEPRECATION: --allow-external has been deprecated and will be removed in the future. Due to changes in the repository protocol, it no longer has any effect."