# python, linux- (PY1001): Unable to install package(s) 'mysql.connector'. Reason: Can't find a pure Python 3 Wheel for package(s) 'mysql.connector'

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, linux, pip

error message:

> (PY1001): Unable to install package(s) 'mysql.connector'. Reason: Can't find a pure Python 3 Wheel for package(s) 'mysql.connector'. See: https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/faq.html#micropip-can-t-find-a-pure-python-wheel for more information.

[website error showing (pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qTwo.png)

- .html script
  the script is trying to using python gathering data from MySQL database, and show in webpage.

already make sure I installed pymysql and mysql-connector-python

```
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
      <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
    </head>

  <body>
    <b><p>title <u><label id="AAA"></label></u> </p></b>
    <br>
  
    <py-config>

      packages = ["mysql.connector"]
    </py-config>


    <py-script>
        import mysql.connector

        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
          host="196.168.100.141",
          user="root",
          password="password123", 
          database="database_db",  
          auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
        )
                        
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        mycursor.execute("SELECT row_01 FROM database")                       
                                                 
        myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
        
        list_01 = []
        
        for row in myresult:
          temp_val = row[0]
          list_01.append(temp_val)
    </py-script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I read through the solution [Unable to install mysql connector for Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33011432/unable-to-install-mysql-connector-for-python-3)

is to using `pip install --allow-external mysql-connector-python mysql-connector-python` , but that need pip version 8, which is pretty old, not works for now, ps the discussion is 7 years ago

---

- additional info showing all installation

```
[root@localhost ~]# pip show pymysql
Name: PyMySQL
Version: 1.0.2
Summary: Pure Python MySQL Driver
Home-page: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/
Author: yutaka.matsubara
Author-email: yutaka.matsubara@gmail.com
License: "MIT"
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
[root@localhost ~]# pip show mysql-connector-python
Name: mysql-connector-python
Version: 8.0.31
Summary: MySQL driver written in Python
Home-page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/index.html
Author: Oracle and/or its affiliates
Author-email:
License: GNU GPLv2 (with FOSS License Exception)
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: protobuf
Required-by:
[root@localhost ~]# pip list
Package                Version
---------------------- -------
mysql-connector        2.2.9
mysql-connector-python 8.0.31
pip                    21.3.1
protobuf               3.19.6
PyMySQL                1.0.2
setuptools             59.6.0
```

I might need other solution , how to deal with this

---

update:
[update error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ixgmr.png)

- error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 567, in open_connection
    self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
BlockingIOError: [Errno 26] Operation in progress

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 435, in eval_code
    .run(globals, locals)
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 304, in run
    coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals)
  File "<exec>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/pooling.py", line 287, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 137, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1108, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 533, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 569, in open_connection
    raise InterfaceError(
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '196.168.100.141:3306' (26 Operation in progress)
```

I'm sure the py script part, aka the mydb input info is correct that I use  `simple .py script` can connect and print the MySQL output

```
    <py-script>
        import mysql.connector

        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
          host="196.168.100.141",
          user="root",
          password="password123", 
          database="database_db",  
          auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
        )
                        
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        mycursor.execute("SELECT row_01 FROM database")                       
                                                 
        myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
        
        list_01 = []
        
        for row in myresult:
          temp_val = row[0]
          list_01.append(temp_val)
    </py-script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [PyScript](https://pyscript.net/) framework, where the Python installation is on the server side of a third-party service and has nothing to do with your local Python installation.

According to PyScript's documentation of [Importing the needed libraries](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#importing-the-needed-libraries), you should declare the libraries you wish to install with the `py-config` tag, which you have somewhat, but by package name `mysql-connector-python`, not the module name `mysql.connector`:

```
packages = ["pymysql", "mysql-connector-python"]
```

This runs, but would not connect to the database at the IP-address `196.168.100.141` from the server end since it is likely available only in your local area network:

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
      <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
    </head>

  <body>
    <b><p>title <u><label id="AAA"></label></u> </p></b>
    <br>
  
    <py-config>

      packages = ["pymysql", "mysql-connector-python"]
    </py-config>


    <py-script>
        import mysql.connector

        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
          host="196.168.100.141",
          user="root",
          password="password123", 
          database="database_db",  
          auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
        )
                        
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        mycursor.execute("SELECT row_01 FROM database")                       
                                                 
        myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
        
        list_01 = []
        
        for row in myresult:
          temp_val = row[0]
          list_01.append(temp_val)
    </py-script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi @blhsing , follow by ur solution, I update the post of that issue, pls take a look

Comment: The IP-address `196.168.100.141` that your database server uses is likely available only in your own local area network and is inaccessible to the server used by PyScript's public service. You can try opening up port 3306 of your database server to the public Internet if security risks aren't an issue.

Comment: ok, I will try it tomorrow, are you fine  I mark ur ans solved if this work, in tomorrow, not immediately

Comment: or instead of open mysql port to public (avoid risk), is there other way to deal with`The IP-address 196.168.100.141 that your database server uses is likely available only in your own local area network and is inaccessible to the server used by PyScript's public service`, aka connect website to MySQL successfully. Cause execute simple .py script to do so is working, that I want to show the result in website